# Efficient Network Clustering Algorithm for Million Node Networks

Tags: clustering, social-networks, network-analysis

I am looking for a clustering algorithm that is scalable up to large sparse undirected, unweighted networks (10-40M nodes, 10-80M edges). The most important aspects I care about are scaling efficiency to this size network and maybe consistency/stability. I'm mostly interested in this as a way to try and understand the network in more detail. I'm open to many types of clustering (including overlapping clusters, etc.).

Comment: Have you checked out [networkit](https://networkit.github.io/)?

Comment: There they use _Staudt, C. L., & Meyerhenke, H. (2015). Engineering parallel algorithms for community detection in massive networks. IEEE Transactions on Parallel and Distributed Systems, 27(1), 171-184._ for their **community detection** algorithm.

Comment: Check also out the results from the very recent [PACE Challenge on _Cluster Editing_](https://pacechallenge.org/2021/cluster-editing/).

Comment: Another reference from Networkit is _Raghavan, U. N., Albert, R., & Kumara, S. (2007). Near linear time algorithm to detect community structures in large-scale networks. Physical review E, 76(3), 036106._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Louvain algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louvain_method) does just this, and it easily handles graphs of this size. It is implemented in most, if not all, graph libraries. In particular, [Networkit](https://networkit.github.io/) provides a fast parallel implementation. If you are interested in clusters only, you may use [a dedicated implementation](https://sourceforge.net/projects/louvain/) like the generalized version [documented in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2518).

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. And thanks to you and Pål for the reference to NetworKit which is such an improvement over NetworkX for memory use and performance!